# Text Field Tag Placeholder Returning As Value

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, placeholder

I have a form and inside the form there is a text_field_tag. It is written as this...

```
<%= text_field_tag "search",  :placeholder => 'Enter search term...' %>
```

However, when the HTML is generated this returns in the page source...

```
<input id="search" name="search" type="text" value="{:placeholder=&gt;&quot;Enter search 
term...&quot;}" />
```

Why is it doing this and how do I fix it so that placeholder works?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The second parameter of the text_field_tag is the value. Give it nil to have it empty:

```
<%= text_field_tag "search", nil, :placeholder => 'Enter search term...' %>
```

And give it a String to have a default value:

```
<%= text_field_tag "search", 'Enter search term...' %>
```

Add an onclick event to empty it with jQuery:

```
<%= text_field_tag "search", 'Enter search term...', :onclick => 'if($(this).val()=="Enter search term..."){$(this).val("");};' %>
```

## Edit 2016:

Nowadays, most of the browsers now support the [HTML 5 `placeholder`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp), which allows us to do this in a cleaner way:

```
<%= text_field_tag 'search', nil, placeholder: 'Enter search term' %>
# which produces the following HTML:
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter search term">
```

[jsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/wzxwjgdt/1/)

Comment: You're welcome :) Can you check my post as the answer please?

Comment: Yeah sorry. I was going to when I was playing with some css and got distracted.

Comment: <%= text_field_tag "search", 'Enter search term...' %>
 this is not working in rails 5