# How to add a placeholder to a text_field_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following line in my form:

```
= text_field_tag :mother_name, nil, id: 'mother_name_autocomplete', class: 'form-group form-control', autocomplete: 'off', data: {provide: 'typeahead'}
```

How can I add a placehodler to this field?

Answer (score 12):

if you are using `text_field_tag` then you can do something like this.

```
<%= text_field_tag :mother_name, nil, placeholder: 'Some text' %>
```

notice that second argument is `nil`.

Answer (score 4):

With `rails >= 3.0`, you can simply use the `placeholder` option.

```
f.text_field :mother_name, :placeholder => "mother_name_autocomplete"
```

You can find more reference here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html

Answer (score 1):

> For Example, id = "input_name", value = nil, placeholder = "Enter your name"

So the tag is provided as,

```
 <%= text_field_tag 'input_name', nil, placeholder: "Enter your name" %>
```

The above code will be generated as mentioned below,

```
<input type="text" name="input_name" id="input_name" placeholder="Enter your name">
```

Read more about the tags here :
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html

Answer (score -3):

```
<%= text_field_tag "search", 'Enter search term...' %>
```

Add an onclick event to empty it with jQuery:

```
<%= text_field_tag "search", 'Enter search term...', :onclick => 'if($(this).val()=="Enter search term..."){$(this).val("");};' %>
```

Reference:- [Text Field Tag Placeholder Returning As Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13481986/text-field-tag-placeholder-returning-as-value)

Comment: There's absolutely no need to do this, now that placeholder is properly supported as a DOM attribute.