# Override a default value in a rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form with different inputs, one needs a default value.

For exemple

```
<%= f.label :salary, "Salary" %>
<%= f.text_field :salary, value: "Default salary" %>
```

Imagine, I fill in salary with, **80K** I save my form.
The show works well, I can see the **80K** as expected...

The problem is when I edit other fields in my form... I have **Default salary** back and  I want to keep **80K**

What should I do please?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901386/how-to-add-a-placeholder-to-a-text-field-tag/36901710.  That shows how to set up placeholder text in a rails text_field

Comment: I don't want a placeholder I want a default value to be recorded or changed

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the object is a new record. If it is, you fill with the default value, otherwise you fill with the object value. Something like this:

```
<%= f.label :salary, "Salary" %>
<%= f.text_field :salary, value: (f.object.new_record? ? 
"Default salary" : f.object.salary) %>
```

Hope this helps, good luck

Comment: It helps a bit thanks but it seems that my problem is more complicated than i though :)

Answer (score 2):

You can set default values in the new action where your are making object for that from.

```
def new
  @obj = SomeClass.new
  @obj.salary = "Default salary"
  ...
end
```

And another solution is that you define the default value in the migration file on that modal as following.

```
change_column :some_class, :salary, :number, default: "Default salary"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just fill in with the actual value if it exists or use your default value otherwise.

```
<%= f.label :salary, "Salary" %>
<%= f.text_field :salary, value: (f.object.salary || "Default salary") %>
```